# What is QString::toUtf8 doing?

Tags: qt, utf-8, utf

This may sounds like a obvious question, but I'm missing something about either how UTF-8 is encoded or how the toUtf8 function works.

Let's look at a very simple program

```
QString str("Müller");
qDebug() << str << str.toUtf8().toHex();
```

Then I get the output

```
"Müller" "4dc383c2bc6c6c6572"
```

But I got the idea the the [letter ü](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm) should have been encoded as *c3bc* and not *c383c2bc*.

Thanks
Johan

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485602/qt-convert-unicode-entites

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on the encoding of your source code.

I tend to think that your file is already encoded in UTF-8, the character ü being encoded as C3 BC.

You're calling the `QString::QString ( const char * str )` constructor which, according to http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#QString-8, converts your string to unicode using the QString::fromAscii() method which by default considers the input as Latin1 contents.

As C3 and BC are both valid in Latin 1, representing respectively Ã and ¼, converting them to UTF-8 will lead to the following characters:

Ã (C3) -> C3 83

¼ (BC) -> C2 BC

which leads to the string you get: "4d **c3 83 c2 bc** 6c 6c 65 72"

To sum things up, it's double UTF-8 encoding.

There are several options to solve this issue:

1) You can convert your source file to Latin-1 using your favorite text editor.

2) You can properly escape the ü character into \xFC in the litteral string, so the string won't depend on the file's encoding.

3) you can keep the file and string as UTF-8 data and use `QString str = QString::fromUtf8 ("Müller");`

**Update**: This issue is no longer relevant in QT5. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8 states that the constructor now uses `QString::fromUtf8()` internally instead of `QString::fromAscii()`. So, as long as UTF-8 encoding is used consistently, it will be used by default.

Answer (score 2):

Running your code I get expected result

`"4dc3bc6c6c6572"`

I think the problem is with your input not output.
Check the encoding of your source file and look at
[`void QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings ( QTextCodec * codec ) [static]`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings)