# Convert QString into QByteArray with either UTF-8 or Latin1 encoding

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8, latin1, qbytearray

I would like to covert a QString into either a utf8 or a latin1 QByteArray, 
but today I get everything as utf8.

And I am testing this with some char in the higher segment of latin1 higher than 0x7f, 
where the german ü is a good example.

If I do like this:

```
QString name("\u00fc"); // U+00FC = ü
QByteArray utf8;
utf8.append(name);
qDebug() << "utf8" << name << utf8.toHex();

QByteArray latin1;
latin1.append(name.toLatin1());
qDebug() << "Latin1" << name << latin1.toHex();

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("ISO 8859-1");
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(name);
qDebug() << "ISO 8859-1" << name << encodedString.toHex();
```

I get the following output.

```
utf8 "ü" "c3bc" 
Latin1 "ü" "c3bc" 
ISO 8859-1 "ü" "c3bc"
```

As you can see I get the unicode 0xc3bc everywhere, where I would expect to get the Latin1 0xfc for step 2 and 3.

My guess is that I should get something like this:

```
utf8 "ü" "c3bc" 
Latin1 "ü" "fc" 
ISO 8859-1 "ü" "fc"
```

What is going on here?

/Thanks

---

Links to some character tables:

- http://www.utoronto.ca/web/HTMLdocs/NewHTML/iso_table.html
- http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/

---

This code was build and executed on a Ubuntu 10.04 based system.

```
$> uname -a
Linux frog 2.6.32-28-generic-pae #55-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 10 22:34:08 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
$> env | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.utf8
```

And if I try to use

```
utf8.append(name.toUtf8());
```

I get this output

```
utf8 "ü" "c383c2bc" 
Latin1 "ü" "c3bc" 
ISO 8859-1 "ü" "c3bc"
```

So the latin1 is unicode and the utf8 is double encoded...

This must depend on some system settings?

---

If I run this (could not get the .name() to build)

```
qDebug() << "system name:"      << QLocale::system().name();
qDebug() << "codecForCStrings:" << QTextCodec::codecForCStrings();
qDebug() << "codecForLocale:"   << QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->name();
```

Then I get this:

```
system name: "en_US" 
codecForCStrings: 0x0 
codecForLocale: "System"
```

---

*Solution*

If I specify that it is UTF-8 I am using so the different classes know about this, 
then it works.

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

qDebug() << "system name:"      << QLocale::system().name();
qDebug() << "codecForCStrings:" << QTextCodec::codecForCStrings()->name();
qDebug() << "codecForLocale:"   << QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->name();

QString name("\u00fc"); 
QByteArray utf8;
utf8.append(name);
qDebug() << "utf8" << name << utf8.toHex();

QByteArray latin1;
latin1.append(name.toLatin1());
qDebug() << "Latin1" << name << latin1.toHex();

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("latin1");
QByteArray encodedString = codec->fromUnicode(name);
qDebug() << "ISO 8859-1" << name << encodedString.toHex();
```

Then I get this output:

```
system name: "en_US" 
codecForCStrings: "UTF-8" 
codecForLocale: "UTF-8" 
utf8 "ü" "c3bc" 
Latin1 "ü" "fc" 
ISO 8859-1 "ü" "fc"
```

And that looks like it should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things to know:

- execution character page

There's something called *execution* character set in the C++ standard which is the term that describes what the output of string and character literals will be in the binary produced by compiler. You can read about it in the [1.1 Character sets](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets) subsection of *1 Overview* section in *The C Preprocessor's Manual* on http://gcc.gnu.org site.

Question:
What will be produced as a result of `"\u00fc"` string literal?

Answer:
It depends on what the execution character set is. In case of gcc (which is what you're using) it's by default UTF-8 unless you specify something different with `-fexec-charset` option. You can read about this and other options controlling preprocessing phase in the [3.11 Options Controlling the Preprocessor](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) subsection of *3 GCC Command Options* section in *GCC's Manual* on http://gcc.gnu.org site. Now when we know that execution character set is UTF-8 we know that `"\u00fc"` will be translated to UTF-8 encoding of `U+00FC` Unicode's code point which is a sequence of two bytes `0xc3 0xbc`.

- [`QString::QString ( const char * str )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#QString-8) and [`QByteArray & QByteArray::append ( const QString & str )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qbytearray.html#append-2) depend on global state

The QString's constructor taking `char *` calls [`QString QString::fromAscii ( const char * str, int size = -1 )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromAscii) which uses codec set with [`void QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings ( QTextCodec * codec )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings) (if any codec had been set) or does the same thing as [`QString QString::fromLatin1 ( const char * str, int size = -1 )`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#fromLatin1) (in case no codec had been set).

Question:
What codec will be used by QString's constructor to decode two byte sequence (`0xc3 0xbc`) it gets?

Answer:
By default no codec is set with `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings()` that's why Latin1 will be used to decode byte sequence. As `0xc3` and `0xbc` are both valid in Latin 1, representing respectively Ã and ¼ (this should already be familiar to you as it was taken directly from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853134/what-is-qstringtoutf8-doing/4853610#4853610) answer to your earlier question) we get QString with these two characters.

- [`qDebug()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdebug.html) is not 8-bit clean

You shouldn't use `QDebug` class to output anything outside of [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/). You have no guarantee what you get.

Test program:

```
#include <QtCore>

void dbg(char const * rawInput, QString s) {

    QString codepoints;
    foreach(QChar chr, s) {
        codepoints.append(QString::number(chr.unicode(), 16)).append(" ");
    }

    qDebug() << "Input: " << rawInput
             << ", "
             << "Unicode codepoints: " << codepoints;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    qDebug() << "system name:"
             << QLocale::system().name();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {

        switch(i) {

        case 1:
            qDebug() << "\nWithout codecForCStrings (default is Latin1)\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            qDebug() << "\nWith codecForCStrings set to UTF-8\n";
            QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
            break;
        case 3:
            qDebug() << "\nWithout codecForCStrings (default is Latin1), with codecForLocale set to UTF-8\n";
            QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(0);
            QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
            break;
        case 4:
            qDebug() << "\nWithout codecForCStrings (default is Latin1), with codecForLocale set to Latin1\n";
            QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(0);
            QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("Latin1"));
            break;
        }

        qDebug() << "codecForCStrings:" << (QTextCodec::codecForCStrings()
                                           ? QTextCodec::codecForCStrings()->name()
                                           : "NOT SET");
        qDebug() << "codecForLocale:"   << (QTextCodec::codecForLocale()
                                           ? QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->name()
                                           : "NOT SET");

        qDebug() << "\n1. Using QString::QString(char const *)";
        dbg("\\u00fc", QString("\u00fc"));
        dbg("\\xc3\\xbc", QString("\xc3\xbc"));
        dbg("LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS", QString("ü"));

        qDebug() << "\n2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)";
        dbg("\\u00fc", QString::fromUtf8("\u00fc"));
        dbg("\\xc3\\xbc", QString::fromUtf8("\xc3\xbc"));
        dbg("LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS", QString::fromUtf8("ü"));

        qDebug() << "\n3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)";
        dbg("\\u00fc", QString::fromLocal8Bit("\u00fc"));
        dbg("\\xc3\\xbc", QString::fromLocal8Bit("\xc3\xbc"));
        dbg("LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS", QString::fromLocal8Bit("ü"));
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Output on mingw 4.4.0 on Windows XP:

```
system name: "pl_PL"

Without codecForCStrings (default is Latin1)

codecForCStrings: "NOT SET"
codecForLocale: "System"

1. Using QString::QString(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "102 13d "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "102 13d "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

With codecForCStrings set to UTF-8

codecForCStrings: "UTF-8"
codecForLocale: "System"

1. Using QString::QString(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "102 13d "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "102 13d "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

Without codecForCStrings (default is Latin1), with codecForLocale set to UTF-8

codecForCStrings: "NOT SET"
codecForLocale: "UTF-8"

1. Using QString::QString(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

Without codecForCStrings (default is Latin1), with codecForLocale set to Latin1

codecForCStrings: "NOT SET"
codecForLocale: "ISO-8859-1"

1. Using QString::QString(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
codecForCStrings: "NOT SET"
codecForLocale: "ISO-8859-1"

1. Using QString::QString(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "

2. Using QString::fromUtf8(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fffd "

3. Using QString::fromLocal8Bit(char const *)
Input:  \u00fc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  \xc3\xbc ,  Unicode codepoints:  "c3 bc "
Input:  LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS ,  Unicode codepoints:  "fc "
```

I'd like to thank **thiago**, **cbreak**, **peppe** and **heinz** from #qt freenode.org IRC channel for showing and helping me to understand issues involved here.

Comment: I'm using a Ubuntu Linux based system and I think he is using utf8 as the default character set.

Comment: @Johan I don't quite get what you mean by *But the utf8 is the only one that is correct?*

Comment: In my first code ü is converted into 0xc3bc, and that is correct. But as a latin1 It should be converted into 0xfc. Just as you output shows. So in my example utf8 is correct as it is, and latin1 is NOT.

Comment: @Johan What does qDebug() << QTextCodec::codecForCStrings().name(); return?

Comment: I need to set both codecForCStrings and setCodecForLocale, or else it do not work as it should...