# what is the effective scope of setCodecfForTr()

Tags: c++, qt, scope

I'm have the following in  `main.cpp` file,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);


    QTextCodec::setCodecForCString(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And the following is the `mainwindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    

    result = new QLabel("Check Result Here:",this);

    result->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(180,30),QSize(161,161)));

    QString m("宁愿看见两个恶魔在拔河，也不愿看见一只天使在跳舞。");

    result->setText(m);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The Chinese character on the `QLabel` can not be displayed normally.

If I modify them into follows, the character can  be displayed normally.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The following is the `mainwindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);    
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCString(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));

    result = new QLabel("Check Result Here:",this);

    result->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(180,30),QSize(161,161)));

    QString m("宁愿看见两个恶魔在拔河，也不愿看见一只天使在跳舞。");

    result->setText(m);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I think its the problem of the scope of function 'setCodeForCString()`, Can someone explain that?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288959/convert-qstring-into-qbytearray-with-either-utf-8-or-latin1-encoding

Comment: Does the `QMainWindow` constructor set the codec?

Comment: I get the problem now. Its not about the scope of setCodeForCString(), the scope of this function is application level global(95% positive?). The reason of showing the abnormal character is that I did not set the character font in my application. I guess there is no default font for characters other English words... Once I set the font, the character can be displayed correctly. Thanks god, wasted two days on that...